# How to safely close Intellij from command line?

Tags: rhel, intellij

I'm using Intellij on my Rhel machine. I often use remote login to work from home. But since Intellij allows only one instance at a time, it needs to be killed to start a new instance remotely. However, this is not a clean close & many times I end up losing some recent changes. So, my question is - Is there a way to cleanly kill the currently running Intellij from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can wrt to the killing itself - use regular `kill` first and give it some time before `kill -9`. YMMV.

There is a Command Line Plugin you can install which allows you to do various things without even starting the IDE, you might want to check if there is something in there to help with a cleaner shutdown:

- [Command Line Tool Support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-tool-support.html)
- [Working with IntelliJ IDEA Features from Command Line](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html)

You could also contact JetBrains - maybe they already have something or maybe they can come up with something in future versions.

Personally I'd go for a VNC-based solution, which allows you to access a VNC server session (or just the local Xorg server with VNC support enabled) from one or more VNC clients which can disconnect and reconnect anytime. There could be other GUI-based apps you might need access to - this method should work for most of them.

Comment: links are broken

Comment: @corvus_192 updated links

Answer (score 0):

Try to get familiar with `screen`.

When you connect from remote first start `screen` and within the `screen` session start IntelliJ. When you are done working, do not logoff but `detach` your screen by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd>

When you want to pick up your work again, from another place for example, you can reattach to the left session by issuing `screen -d -r`

If your session gets interrupted somehow, your `screen` session will keep running and allow you to continue when you reattach.

Comment: IntelliJ is a GUI application, it doesn't run within `screen` and you can't reattach it (well, maybe with Xpra...).

Comment: Right, I should have done some more homework before answering :-) Thought that it also could run from a commandline in some way...